# Symfony PHPUnit tests don't authenticate user

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-4.4, symfony-guard, simple-phpunit

I have a Symfony 4.4 project. Login, authentication, and authorization work fine on web.

To simulate authentication in unit tests, I'm using [Symfony's example](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/http_authentication.html).

...but that's not working. The user is not authenticated in the unit test. I get an Unauthorized with error message "Full authentication is required to access this resource."

My test:

```php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testJsonUserEndpoint()
    {
        $this->logIn();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/json/user');

        $this->assertNotContains('invalid_credentials', $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
    }

    private function logIn()
    {
        $user = self::$container->get(EntityManagerInterface::class)->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByMail('test106@test.com');

        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, $firewallName, ['ROLE_USER']);
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

My firewall:

```yaml
        main:
            anonymous:
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
            remember_me:
                always_remember_me: true
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
            provider: session_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\Authenticator\LoginAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\Authenticator\MobileBridgeAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\Authenticator\BearerTokenAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\Authenticator\HashAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\Authenticator\ClientAuthenticator
                entry_point: App\Security\Authenticator\LoginAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: execute_logout
                target: render_login
```

Unit test failure:

```
1) App\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testJsonUserEndpoint
Failed asserting that '{"status":"invalid_credentials","errors":["Invalid Credentials"],"debug":"Full authentication is required to access this resource.","error":"Unauthorized"}' does not contain "invalid_credentials".
```

How can I authenticate a user in my unit tests without using the login form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I don't store roles in the database with the user -- they're added in my authenticators --  and passing the roles to `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` wasn't enough. I also had to add them to the user in the token:

```php
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
$token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($session_user, $firewallName, ['ROLE_USER']);
```

Actually, it didn't even matter what's in the Token's roles as long as it's an array:

```php
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
$token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($session_user, $firewallName, []);
```